# Batch to delete empty directories (and state which directories aren't empty?)

Tags: file, batch-file, organization

I'm using:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /ad/b/s ^| sort /R') do rd "%%d"
pause
```

which returns:

```
The directory is not empty.
```

for any nonempty directories.  Is there any way for it to list specifically which directories aren't empty instead of a vague statement?  I know it's not much effort to manually check the directories, but this is part of a larger script that I'm trying to make more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rd` returns an `ERRORLEVEL` you can use, just change:

```
rd "%%d"
```

To this:

```
rd "%%d" || (echo Not empty: %%d)
```

To remove error message from `rd` too just redirect `stderr` to `nul`:

```
rd "%%d" 2>nul || (echo Not empty: %%d)
```

Comment: That works great, thanks.  Is there a way to only display the name of the folder, instead of the full path?

Comment: @user2100577 - Try `Not empty: %%~nd`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks.  I'm still just getting used to the weird syntax.

Comment: Make sure to use the `x` as well for folder names because any folder names containing a period will be divided between the `n` and `x`. `echo Not empty: %%~nxd`